# How to snapshot a software release (with GitHub)?

Tags: git, github, release

[This GitHub guide](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-releases/) seems to indicate that `tag`-ing a release snapshots a compiled binary.  I was previously under the assumption that `tag`-ing a release is intended to snapshot the source code state, where the build (or equivalent) directories are often intentionally ignored.  Or is that just performed by a commit of only a version update?

I guess I'm trying to understand a typical process for what version control steps need to be taken for a release.  Here is what I'm imagining so far:

1.

```
git commit -m 'Add new feature'
```

2.

Bump your version number (using [semantic versioning](http://semver.org)) and add the change to staging.

3.

```
git commit -m 'Bump version to X.Y.Z'
```

4.

[Tag the release](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-releases/) by uploading the compiled binary to your remote repository in GitHub

5.

Via GitHub client, sync on your local machine to pull down the update (tag) performed on GitHub.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I was previously under the assumption that tag-ing a release is intended to snapshot the source code state, where the build (or equivalent) directories are often intentionally ignored

That is correct.

"Releases" aren't a native Git concept, but tags are. GitHub uses Git tags for its proprietary releases feature. If you tag revision and push that tag to GitHub, your release will be a source release.

But you *can* optionally [add a binary to a release](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-releases/):

> If you'd like to include binary files along with your release, such as compiled programs, drag and drop or select files manually in the binaries box.

If you want to have binary releases, you can create your release through the GitHub web UI as described in that page.

Alternatively, you can

1. create an annotated tag locally,

   ```
   git tag -a v1.0
   ```
2. push that tag to GitHub, and

   ```
   git push --tags
   ```
3. add your binary release to it, by going to https://github.com/user/repo/tags and clicking the "Edit release notes" link.

   Here you will be able to give your release a name and description and upload your binary files. Once this is done, your release will appear at https://github.com/user/repo/releases, with a download links for your source in `.zip` and `.tar.gz` formats, as well as your binaries in whatever formats you uploaded.